# Image not removed from DOM when nulling src in jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I have the following HTML:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="image" />
```

and that JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {
        $('#image').attr('src', '');
    }
);
```

But my problem is that the image is still there when the code is run.

I have notice by using the Chrome console, that the img element src is getting empty, but the image still there in the web site.

Any idea on how to remove the image? Note, if posible, I prefer to not remove the img element from the dom.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to leave the `<img>` element there, if it doesn't point to a valid image?

Comment: Because I have to modify a big part of my script in case I remove the DOM element. I know this is not the correct way, but I prefer to keep it if posible

Comment: OK, how about creating a 1px*1px transparent image, and resetting the `src` to the address of that image? Since the image element already exists, afaik it will maintain the same size, and so won't disturb the page layout - but it will appear to have been removed. (You can of course reset the dimensions using jQuery if you wish).

Comment: Thanks a lot halfer for your response. I already have fix the issue by removing the img element from the DOM. Kind regads

Comment: Glad you fixed it. If in future you could update your question if you no longer need a response, to avoid unnecessary effort, that would be great `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).load(
    function($)
    {
        $('#image').attr('src', '');
    }
);
```